# I can't find a way to compare the body of emails in python because some of the email contains extra license messages in the end

Tags: python, mbox

I have a problem to compare body emails in python. 
I get the body from text files that contain emails and populate the list with the body of emails:

```
for enum in original_list:
with open(enum, 'r') as f:
    enum = f.read()
    msg = email.message_from_string(enum)
    for part in msg.walk():
        my_body = part.get_payload(decode=True)
        original_data_body.append(my_body)
```

I get the bodies from messages from another file which contains all messages in mbox format. Again with walk and get_payload.

The problem is that the emails in mbox contains in the end extra license messages.

How to remove this extra messages and compare the body of emails?

Answer (score 0):

Is the extra license message always the same? If yes then you can split the string based on that and keep only the first part returned by split which will contain the original message. If its not exactly the same but that there is a pattern that repeat across messages split it on that pattern and return the first part.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the message is always the same. I can split but this this means to hard coded the split. I hope for more elegant way. :(